# getElementsByTagName("tbody") not working. Alternative?

Tags: javascript

I have a `<tbody>` tag that I want to reach via JS.

I get error when trying to get `document.body.getElementsByTagName("tbody")` or `document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")`. Why?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ScgrG/1/)

html

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Are you sure the DOM is ready when you execute that code? Are you executing it by the `<head>` tag? Or is it put after the `<body>` content?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
```

And you need to wrap `tbody` with  `table` tag.

***[See the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/fuMR6/)***

Comment: Does'nt work. [jsfiddle.net/ScgrG/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/ScgrG/1/) Don't understand either what I am missing.

Comment: @Rikard: You are missing the `<table>` tag. Didn't you notice that the data is not layed out as a table? The browser will ignore invalid tags. Right click on the ext and do "Inspect elements". You will see no elements there.

Comment: @Rikard `tbody` must stay in a `table`.

Comment: @Rikard: But you cannot have invalid HTML either.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, wrap your HTML inside a `<table>`.

Secondly, concerning your jsFiddle:

```
var tbodies = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
tbodies.style.display = "none";
```

This will not work. [**`getElementsByTagName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName) returns a list of elements.

If you want to target the first, use:

```
var tbodies = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
```

or if you want to target all `<tbody>`'s, loop through every element and apply the styling to each:

```
for(var i = 0; i < tbodies.length; i++) {
  tbodies[i].style.display = "none";
}
```